# ConEmu doesn't show non-ASCII characters

Tags: cygwin, conemu, non-ascii

I'm using ConEmu (on windows 7) for a few months now. Everything worked fine until today. Indeed, now I can't write non ASCII characters like 'é' : when I press the key, nothing happens.

I'm using cygwin shell, and when using cygwin terminal it works fine.

Same, I know the font handles these characters. When I launch the python interpreter, I can use them.

I'm a bit puzzled right now. Any ideas ?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html

Comment: I've read it. It didn't help :/

Comment: Check your `.inputrc` for "meta" (meta-flag and so on)